# Adding a static Create() method to a custom C# dictionary class

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cocoa

I've got a custom Dictionary implementation that covers a private Dictionary, and provides functionality closer to Apple's NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary in the following two ways:

1. Add() will not throw an exception if key is already present (old
   pair is removed before the add)
2. dictionary["key"] will not throw
   an exception if the key is not present (instead default(TValue) is
   returned)

That's all working great and it's only a few lines of code:

```
public class NSDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> core = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return this.ObjectForKey(key); }
        set { this.SetObjectForKey(value, key); }
    }

    public TValue ObjectForKey(TKey key)
    {
        try
        {
            return core[key];
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return default(TValue);
        }
    }

    public void SetObjectForKey(TValue value, TKey key)
    {
        try
        {
            if ( core.ContainsKey(key) )
            {
                core.Remove(key);
            }

            core.Add(key, value);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return core.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)core).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to avoid exceptions during allocation/initialization by instead returning null on failure. C# constructors don't allow for this, so I have to add static factory methods ('factory' in the obj-c sense) that have this basic structure...

```
public static NSDictionary<TKey, TValue> Create()
{
    try
    {
        return new NSDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Pardon the not-exactly-on-point example, since the only way that 'new' allocation/initialization is going to fail is if we're out of memory, in which case a more heavy-handed approach like a thrown exception might not be the worst thing in the world.*

So goofy example case aside, how would this be done, since calling code needs to know the key/value types and I haven't defined any way here to specify them?

*I use this factory pattern throughout all of our C# projects for all of our custom classes, but this is the first time I've had to do it for a generic container class.*

Weirdly, that method compiles, but the calling code does not:

```
NSDictionary<string, Version> dictionary = NSDictionary.Create();
```

I get:

```
Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'NSDictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments
```

I think the crux of the issue here is that I can't figure out where the '<TKey, TValue>' type declarations should go in this static method situation.

Comment: Is `var dictionary = NSDictionary<string, Version>.Create();` what you are looking for? Or are you asking about something more complicated?

Comment: Why would there ever be an exception? You have no constructor so the default parameterless one is being used. I don't see what there is to catch here. As for the CS0305 one - that's a compiler error, not a runtime exception. It explains exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Sweeper, lol... I could've sworn that I'd already tried putting '<string, Version>' before the '.' but I guess I did not, because your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you! (Is there still no way to accept a comment from my end as the correct answer? If not, re-submit as a formal answer so that I can accept it.)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, ya my example wasn't fantastic. A better example would be a constructor that accepts keys/values as parameters and I need handle the case where they might be null.

Comment: My opinion: in the constructor that accepts key/values, throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the data is null. Do not catch it in the `Create` method. Throwing an exception for unexpected null data is the correct thing to do here IMHO.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama. Noted. Just not what I'm used to or comfortable with. In most cases, I really just want to know if instantiation succeeded or failed. A null/non-null return tells me that in a cleaner way -- and a way I'm much more comfortable with. C++/C#/Java devs will obviously have a strong counter-opinion here; I get that.

Comment: Personally I would follow the Microsoft's way of doing things with .NET (throwing exceptions in the case of unexpected nulls) since that has set the expectations for developers using C# and .NET. Returning `null` to someone who doesn't know the inner workings of the custom dictionary class could be quite counter-intuitive and lead to bugs IMHO. Again, this is my opinion. You do you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since calling code needs to know the key/value types and I haven't defined any way here to specify them?

Well you have. Since `NSDictionary` itself is a generic type, you need to specify its type arguments whenever you call a static method.

```
// Create should probably take "params KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]"?
var dictionary = NSDictionary<string, Version>.Create();
```

That said, I'm not sure why `Create` here would need to return null. As far as I know, the original [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc) in Objective-C doesn't have such an `init`. `initWithObjects:forKeys:` ignores any subsequent duplicate keys, instead of returning null or throwing an exception.

If you want something similar to `initWithObjects:forKeys:` (though I don't recommend this, since you are writing ***C#***), you can add an `Add` method, allowing your C# `NSDictionary` to use [collection initialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
public void Add(TKey, key, TValue value) 
{
    if (!core.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        core.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dictionary = new NSDictionary<string, string> {
    { "a", "b" },
    { "a", "c" }, // this will not be added
    { "b", "d" }
};
```

Also, as an aside, I would recommend not using exception handling to implement `ObjectForKey` and `SetObjectForKey`. You can just check `ContainsKey` to avoid the exception:

```
public TValue ObjectForKey(TKey key)
{
    if (core.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return core[key];
    } 
    else 
    {
        return default;
    }
}

public void SetObjectForKey(TValue value, TKey key)
{
    if (core.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        core[key] = value;
    } 
    else 
    {
        core.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```